# Getting each <th> on the Table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, gui-testing

I have a table that are strutured like:

```
<Table>
<tr class="x1">
 <th>test</th>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="x2">
 <th>test2</th>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="x3">
 <th>test3</th>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I take the values from `<th>`?

My Idea, is: *create a for that will run around the table getting each `<th>`*.

**Is it possible? Anyone have any idea that how can I do this using selenium-webdriver (JAVA)**

**My solution for this**

`ArrayList<String> tableList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(int i = 1; i<=NUMBEROFROWSINYOURTABLE;i++){
                    tableList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='heatmap-container']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/th")).getAttribute("title"));
                        }`

But you can follow the example of the answer of @AndyPerfect too, :)

Comment: Normally, all of the `<th>` tags go in the first `<tr>`

Comment: Yes, but on this case, Every TR have a TH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example is in Python, but it should give you an idea of how to do it. Essentially, get the table element by whatever means you have available. Then, on that element, call findElements searching for all elements with tag name of "th". That will give you a List of all `th` elements within that specific table. Then, just iterate over the elements and print their values or whatever.

```
table_element = driver.find_element_by_id("tableid")
th_elements = table_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("th")
for element in th_elements:
    print element.text
```

In Java, it will look something like this

```
WebElement tableElement = driver.findElement(By.id("tableid"));
List<WebElement> thElements = tableElement.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
for (int i = 0; i < thElements.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(thElements.get(i).getText());
}
```

Comment: Following is the code in JAVA                                    List<WebElement> tableElement = driver.findElements(By.id("tableid"));
List<WebElement> thElements = tableElement.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
for (int i = 0; i < thElements.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(thElements.get(i).getText())
}

Comment: Looking your example, i create this: http://pastebin.com/T5tr429L it's working, thank you Andy! Now, before this script run, I need to verify how many numbers of `<th>` have in my table, do you have any idea how to do this? I think that i need to create another FOR before that..